# Mac open command without any windows

Tags: macos, mac

I'm using open command to open a `.zip` file that contains an `.app` with the following:

```
open my_zip.zip
```

I need to use open because it's important to use the default application (it's part of a script) and using `open` is a must.

Any idea how can i suppress the actual opening of the window?

Comment: You can try: `-j`, `--hide` which Launches the app hidden, or `-g`, `--background` which Does not bring the application to the foreground.

Comment: @kenorb thanks for the replay but i've tried all those options already and it still opens a window.

Comment: What kind of window is opened? Which application do you use to open your zip files?

Comment: @kenorb finder is opened.

Comment: Archive Utility `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/`has its own prefs as to whether it will open the unzipped file in a new window. Not sure how you would override that, but it might be a start.

Comment: If it's opened by Finder, and you don't want it, which app you expect to open it instead? Something like `unzip`? If so, you should [change your file associations](http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/25/change-file-associations-in-mac-os-x/) to use the expected app to deal with that kind of files. See also: [Change file association in terminal](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/91522/22781) if this is what you mean.

Comment: Finder can't unzip files. If this is for general distribution rather than home use, there's no way to specify anything other than Archive Utility to unzip it, as you couldn't be certain they would have anything else.